# Promises in JavaScript not executing propertly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have this series of steps that needs to be completed in order:

1. Validate an object
2. Fetch an image URL using Bing's image search API
3. Add the found URLs to the object
4. Make a post request and send the object

A sample object looks like:

```
`{
    options: [{
      text: 'Pizza',
      votes: 0,
      imageURL: ""
    }, {
      text: 'Hot Dog',
      votes: 0,
      imageURL: ""
    }]
  };`
```

Because the order in this series, I am using promises to make sure everything goes in the order specified above. So far I have:

```js
  function validatePoll() {
    var isValid = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.poll.options.length; i++) {
      if (!$scope.poll.options[i].text) {
        isValid = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    return isValid;
  }

  let promiseURL = function(searchTerm) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      $http.get('https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search?q=' + searchTerm + '&count=1&offset=0&mkt=en-us&safeSearch=Strict', {
        headers: {
          'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        }
      }).success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        resolve(response);
      }).error(function (err, status) {
        reject(err);
      })
    })
  };

  let fetchImageURL = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.poll.options.length; i++) {
      console.log(promiseURL($scope.poll.options[i].text));
    }
  }

  $scope.submitChoice = function() {
    var isValid = validatePoll();
    if(isValid) {
      fetchImageURL();
    } else {
      console.log("Not Valid Poll");
    }
  }
```

But what ends up happening is the *console.log(promiseURL($scope.poll.options[i].text));* in the fetchImageURL returns an unresolved promise instead of the response string I want instead. How might I be able to fix the code to ensure that:

1. A call to promiseURL is made with the proper argument
2. A response is received and can be parsed
3. The parsed information can be added to the imageURL property in the polls object

Comment: what you get if run console.log promiseURL($scope.poll.options[i].text).then(function(res){console.log(res)});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing the printout of the Promise because you're printing out the promise. You need to be handling the promise resolve/reject. What you should be calling is:

```
promiseURL($scope.poll.options[i].text)
   .then(function(data){
      console.log("Success",data)
   })
   .catch(function(error){
      console.log("Error",error")
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Promises are usually used as follows:

```
promise.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result); // "Stuff worked!"
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err); // Error: "It broke"
});
```

Where the `promise` itself looks like:

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // do a thing, possibly async, then…

  if (/* everything turned out fine */) {
    resolve("Stuff worked!");
  }
  else {
    reject(Error("It broke"));
  }
});
```

It doesn't look like, in your loop, you're calling `then` on `promiseURL($scope.poll.options[i].text)`.  Try doing something like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.poll.options.length; i++) {
  promiseURL($scope.poll.options[i].text).then(function(result) {
      console.log(result); // "Stuff worked!"
  });
}
```

See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises for a great primer on promises.